# Is there a way to have zero decimal after the decimal point in a number input field

Tags: html

So, I have an input field of type number:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" step = "0.01">
```

I would like "3." to be accepted as a valid number there. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: In which browser did you try it ? With safari and chrome, it works like a charm.

Comment: Uh. I am trying on Chrome. So you enter "3." and validate and the input is validated?
see: http://imgur.com/a/6BT2Z

Comment: Yes, on Chrome (mac, version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)), it works like a charm.

Comment: Ok thanks for trying it. I have the same browser version but it doesn't work. No idea what's going on, though IE works fine indeed.